# How to set User Role with Identity in MVC application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, identity

I have this project which is school management system, i have created Roles(**Teacher,Admin,Staff)** now i can assign what role is allowed to be viewed in each page and i want the **Teacher** Role to be more specific cos i have this page where the teacher can see all the list of subject that she/he teaches.

Now my problem is when the teacher login, i want all the subject of the current teacher who login can see her subjects only, right now with my role as (Teacher) they can see all the list of subject from other teachers too. Any idea on how to solve this? or what are the things i should add or learn to achieve my goal? i heard about **MVC identity** is it the one responsible for fixing this issue. appreciate if u guys could give me idea on how to deal with this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand your problem correctly.what you are looking for is **Resource Based Authorization (Authorization depends upon the resource being accessed)**. As far as I know, this can not be done with declarative security.

In order to gain such flexibility, you have to call an authorization function inside the action method.
Depending on the result of that authorization function, you can return 403 or the required resource.

Speaking of your requirement, extract the user id inside your action method and filter out other teachers' subjects.
If you are using ASP.Net Identity this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) may help you to get started.